# How do I enable bundles (crafting) in hardcore mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I sat down and started playing the other night for the first time in over a year, and the world spawned me in a vast desert. Rabbits and sticks until the zombies almost ate me at dusk... I get to looking what can be done with rabbit pelts, and the bundle looked awesome.

I was surprised when the recipe didn't work. Seems Mojang never completed this item because of tablet players not being able to use it with touch or something... so how do I turn this on in hardcore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle's crafting recipe has not yet been added to the game. It was previously available from Creative mode, but has since changed back to only being accessible via a command.

If you were playing in Survival (or Creative), you'd be able to allow cheats and use:

```
/give @s minecraft:bundle
```

Unfortunately, since you're playing in Hardcore, bundles are currently not obtainable for you.

Comment: Rumors say that it will be added, finally, in 1.20